# How to use rich:effect with a4j:support and reRender

Tags: javascript, jsf, dom-events, richfaces, ajax4jsf

On my JSF-page, I'm showing some content based on the value of a checkbox. How can I attach an effect (like fading in and out) when this content is re-rendered? Is there an event like `onRender` or something?

Here is what I got so far, but the effect is not showing:

```
<t:selectBooleanCheckbox title="Yes" label="Yes" value="#{myBean.booleanValue}">
   <a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onchange" reRender="panel"/
</t:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<t:div id="panel">
     <rich:effect name="hideDiv" for="myPanelGrid" type="Opacity" params="duration:0.8,from:1.0,to:0.1"/>
     <rich:effect name="showDiv" for="myPanelGrid" type="Opacity" params="duration:0.8,from:0.1,to:1.0"/>
   <t:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{myBean.booleanValue}" id="myPanelGrid">
...
...
...
   </t:panelGrid>
</t:div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've forgotten is event property.

```
<rich:effect event="onmouseout" name="hideDiv" for="myPanelGrid" type="Opacity" params="duration:0.8,from:1.0,to:0.1"/>
```

Also you can show an effect with a js call if you like.

```
<rich:effect name="hideDiv" for="myPanelGrid" type="Opacity" params="duration:0.8,from:1.0,to:0.1"/>

<input type="button" onclick="hideDiv" value="Hide" />
```

More details can be found here, [Richfaces-demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/effect.jsf?c=effect&tab=usage)

Comment: umm.. u forgot the parentheses after hideDiv call.. so it should be <input type="button" onclick="hideDiv()" value="Hide" />